# jQuery each: If element is in the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, each

Why if I have several divs, which I want to give different height depending on the content. He always takes the height from the first condition.

```js
$('.box-site-promo').each(function(index) {

  console.log($(this));

  if ($(this).find('.box-site-tags')) {
    heightBox = 200;
    console.log(index + " " + heightBox);
  } else if ($(this).find('.box-site-authors')) {
    heightBox = 100;
    console.log(index + " " + heightBox);
  } else {
    heightBox = 300;
    console.log(index + " " + heightBox);
  }

  $(this).height(heightBox);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box-site-promo"> A
  <div class="box-site-tags">some tags</div>
</div>
<div class="box-site-promo"> B
  <div class="box-site-authors">authors</div>
</div>
<div class="box-site-promo"> C
  <div class="box-site-tags">some tags</div>
</div>
<div class="box-site-promo"> D </div>
```

Comment: So you want to set height to div's based on the class that is all right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use length to know if the div has descendants. As in the documentation says, find returns  jQuery collection. Check it this snippet. Regards

```js
$('.box-site-promo').each(function(index) {

  //console.log($(this));

  if ($(this).find('.box-site-tags').length > 0) {
    heightBox = 200;
    console.log(index + " " + heightBox);
  } else if ($(this).find('.box-site-authors').length > 0) {
    heightBox = 100;
    console.log(index + " " + heightBox);
  } else {
    heightBox = 300;
    console.log(index + " " + heightBox);
  }

  $(this).height(heightBox);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box-site-promo"> A
  <div class="box-site-tags">some tags</div>
</div>
<div class="box-site-promo"> B
  <div class="box-site-authors">authors</div>
</div>
<div class="box-site-promo"> C
  <div class="box-site-tags">some tags</div>
</div>
<div class="box-site-promo"> D </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition is always `true` because [`$.fn.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) returns a `jQuery` object, which always evaluates to `true` regardless of whether any matching elements have been found or not.

To check whether the object contains any elements you can check its [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property:

```
if ($(this).find('.box-site-tags').length > 0)
```

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
$(".box-site-promo").each(function(index) {
  var $this = $(this), heightBox = 300;
  
  if ($this.find(".box-site-tags").length > 0) {
    heightBox = 200;
  } else if ($this.find(".box-site-authors").length > 0) {
    heightBox = 100;
  }
  
  console.log(index + " " + heightBox);
  $this.height(heightBox);
});
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box-site-promo"> A
  <div class="box-site-tags">some tags</div>
</div>
<div class="box-site-promo"> B
  <div class="box-site-authors">authors</div>
</div>
<div class="box-site-promo"> C
  <div class="box-site-tags">some tags</div>
</div>
<div class="box-site-promo"> D </div>
```